# Multiple Gateways of different type on Microsoft Azure Virtual Network?

Tags: azure, cloud, gateway

I currently have a VNET that is linked to an ExpressRoute connection that has a Gateway to a local on-premise network.

I would like to add a secondary Gateway that would connect this VNET to another VNET in the same subscription.

Is this possible?

In the *.netcfg file of the VNET, the type of the Gateway to on-prem is 'Dedicated'. I have been told you can add a secondary of the same 'IPsec'. However, when I executed New-AzureVirtualNetworkGateway in Azure PowerShell, it is consistently coming back with 'An internal error has occurred'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is exactly your case, but please have a look at [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/expressroute-howto-coexist-classic/) and comments below it.